# rails and rmagick and webfaction

Tags: rmagick, webfaction

I am having a problem loading imagemagick and rmagick on webfaction.

I have installed a rails app called Balderapp that organizes images.

I can't seem to upload the image through balder.

Balder uses imagemagick and rmagick

when i use the console and do this I get a nill as a return making me think rmagick is not working

irb(main):003:0> require 'RMagick'
=> nil

thx

sg

Answer (score 1):

The general steps are:

1. Install ImageMagick from source in your home directory.
2. Install the RMagick gem, linked to the ImageMagick libraries that you built in step 1.

Detailed steps are available in [WebFaction's procedure for installing ImageMagick and RMagick](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#installing-imagemagick-and-rmagick).

Answer (score 0):

On Web faction make sure your are in the correct folder `cd  $HOME/webapps/app` app is the name of your app. Make sure the rmagick gem is installed `./bin/gem list`

in ./bin/irb then this should work:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'
```

if you are using ruby 1.8.* then do not forget to do the `require 'rubygems'`